# If a user is only ever looking at their own data - is there any XSS risk?

Tags: php, security, xss

If my site will only ever allow users to see their own submitted data, and never ever data another user has submitted (i.e. no general 'posts' etc) - then is there actually a XSS risk on my site?

I'm still going to work towards XSS solutions (like httmlspecialchars() etc) - but I'm curious if an attacker can gain anything by looking at their own XSS attack?

Comment: You should always be using `htmlspecialchars()` when putting variable data into HTML anyway, or you're probably going to end up with broken HTML, among other problems.

Comment: yep - thanks Brad - I'm implimenting that for those exact reasons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An attacker cannot gain anything by using cross-site scripting techniques on themselves. The intent of cross-site scripting is to manipulate page elements displayed to the user in a malicious way, be it phishing or reading a cookie. In other words, the attack can only affect client-side entities.

However, it is important to keep in mind what "user only ever looking at their own data" means.

Suppose I have a website where users can have a private profile, viewable only to themselves. There is a text input element on the page that allows users to enter their website URL. Now suppose the form to update a user's profile uses GET.

A page update submission might look like this:

http://www.example.com/privateprofile.pl?action=update&userwebpage=http://www.example.net

An attacker might exploit this by tricking the user into loading the URL:

http://www.example.com/privateprofile.pl?action=update&userwebpage=[malicious_js_code_here]

This is a fairly trivial example, of course, but hopefully it demonstrates the general concept. The concern is that there is the possibility that they may be able to trick the user into entering the XSS themselves. Of course, the viability of an XSS attack like this depends on your specific implementation.

Comment: but thats a URL modification - which I could never stop them clicking a link - that seems more like CSRF - which I have protection against already (i.e. by denying form submission if they never requested that specific form)?

Comment: The example I gave is just an illustration of how one could potentially mount an attack on the system you described. It's good to hear that you have anti-CSRF measures in place. The system you described could be secure if implemented correctly, but unless there's a specific need to allow non-encoded user input I would err on the side of caution.

Comment: It could be not a form. You can have XSS in page number for example. There is no form to fill to request the 2nd page. But an attacker can use javascript instead of number in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no real risk if all their data is privately-viewed. The whole point of XSS is to do a drive-by to hijack a session or other personal information in another user's browser. If there is no such opportunity, then there is no such thing as XSS.

Comment: This is wrong.  See the other two answers for the reason why.

Comment: No, it's definitely still correct. The accepted answer is not an XSS attack at all; it's more of phishing than anything else.

Comment: OK, so XSS requires 2 things: a vulnerability, and a user-editable page that is displayed publicly. The accepted answer is contrived, since you can't update a personal page with just a link. You have to have a login as well. That's how the original question is phrased as well, so therefore if there is no publicly viewable yet user-editable data, there is no risk for XSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes- that doesn't protect you at all.  It's the normal scenario in fact.  The thing you have to consider is that if a hacker can plant an XSS into your site using a URL, then convince someone else to open that URL, then your users' data (cookies, passwords, etc) can be stolen.

Comment: but if User A implants XSS into THEIR data, which only they can see - how can User B actually be shown that data? The only way is if User B logs in as User A, in which case they will still only see User A data?

Comment: Even if only User A can see it, once User B can plant code into the page, it's all over.  He can write some Javascript to track User A's keystrokes, get cookie information, etc, and send it via an Ajax call to User B's server somewhere.

Comment: but how does User B ever get to User A data? They have to be logged in as User A to plant it in the first place? Therefore they already have full access to the data?

Comment: @Laurencei No... If User B induces User A to click on an XSS modification of your site URL, then User A will log in himself, as normal, unaware that malicious code has been injected into the page he's viewing.

Comment: but thats a URL modification - which I could never stop them clicking a link - that seems more like CSRF - which I have protection against already (i.e. by denying form submission if they never requested that specific form)?

Comment: That's the whole point of XSS though.  Of course you can never stop a user from clicking a link -- that's why you have to validate any input to your site (query strings, form posts), and make sure not to naively inject these parameters into your DOM, SQL Statements, etc.